# ReactJS toggleSlider is not working upon 'onClick' of <IconButton>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I building a ReactJs web application. To develop the Navigation bar component, I am using a slider that moves from right to left once an arrow button is clicked.

```
<IconButton onClick={toggleSlider("right", true)}>
```

Following is the full code I am using to develop the Navbar slider:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/styles";
import MobileRightMenuSlider from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";

import {
    AppBar,
    Toolbar,
    ListItem,
    ListItemIcon,
    IconButton,
    ListItemText,
    Avatar,
    Divider,
    List,
    Typography,
    Box
} from "@material-ui/core";

import {
    ArrowBack,
    AssignmentInd,
    Home,
    Apps,
    ContactMail

} from "@material-ui/icons";

import avatar from "../Assets/Images/avatar.png";

//CSS styles
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    menuSliderContainer:{
        width: 250,
        background: "#511",
        height: "30rem"
    },
    avatar:{
        display: "block",
        margin: "0.5rem auto",
        height: "6rem",
        width: "6rem"
    },
    listItem:{
        color: "tan"
    }
});

const menuItems = [
    {
        listIcon: <Home/>,
        listText: "Home"
    },
    {
        listIcon: <AssignmentInd/>,
        listText: "Resume"
    },
    {
        listIcon: <Apps/>,
        listText: "Portfolio"
    },    
    {
        listIcon: <ContactMail/>,
        listText: "Contact"
    },    
    {
        listIcon: <Home/>,
        listText: "Home"
    }
];

const Navbar = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        right: false
    });

    const toggleSlider = (slider, open) => () =>{
        setState({...state, [slider]:open});
    };

    const classes = useStyles();

    const sideList = slider =>(
        <Box component="div" className={classes.menuSliderContainer}>
            <Avatar src={avatar} className={classes.avatar} alt="Pawara Siriwardhane"/>
            <Divider/>
            <List>
                {menuItems.map((lsItem,key)=>(
                    <ListItem button key={key}>
                        <ListItemIcon className={classes.listItem}>
                            {lsItem.listIcon}
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={lsItem.listText} className={classes.listItem}/>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </Box>
    )

    return (
        <>
            <Box component="nav">
                <AppBar position="static" style={{background:"#222"}}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton onClick={toggleSlider("right", true)}>
                            <ArrowBack style={{color: "tomato"}}/>
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="h5" style={{color:"tan"}}> 
                            Portfolio 
                        </Typography>
                        <MobileRightMenuSlider
                            anchor="right"
                            Open={state.right} 
                        >
                            {sideList("right")}
                        </MobileRightMenuSlider>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Once the `<IconButton>` is clicked, the slider should move from left to right to left. But it does not work. The slider is kept hidden as it was, and it does not appear once the button is clicked. I cannot figure out the what is the reason for this error.

I am much obliged if somebody can please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Screenshot of the NavBar
[image: Sidebar is not working onClick of the IconButton]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the **Open** to **open** in **MobileRightMenuSlider**

```
<MobileRightMenuSlider
  anchor={"right"}
  open={state.right} 
>
  {sideList("right")}
</MobileRightMenuSlider>
```

this makes the drawer to appear from right

Comment: Absolutely. I was concerned about the onClick function.

Comment: hehe.. these small things annoys very much sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<IconButton onClick={toggleSlider("right", true)}>
```

Need to change to

```
<IconButton onClick={() => toggleSlider("right", true)}>
```